Is it more safe to run Wine on chroot or Docker?
I've always known that a malware running inside wine can affect the Linux system as well. I was looking around and found these container solution:

Chroot
Docker

What I want to do is I want to install wine in a container(chrooted or docked) so that it can run securely.
The reason I am trying to do this is beacuse I am afraid of a virus leaking and controlling the whole Linux system. What if there is a virus written specifically for wine that can take control of the whole system.
Can a container really help me secure my system?
VMWare seems heavy. I don't think that would be a good way to work.
I to choose between chroot and docker.
Which one is better?

I've removed the WSL tag from your question since you don't seem to be asking about it.  Wine and WSL are pretty much the converse of each other - Wine is about running Windows apps on Ubuntu; WSL is about running Ubuntu on Windows.

@NotTheDr01ds Thanks for that. Any idea what can we add there?

What "container solution" did you find? What would you be chrooting into? What docker image would you be using? A dockerized Linux on which you would install wine and your game? Please [edit] your question and give us more detail about the setup you are thinking of so we can understand.

Thanks @NotTheDr01ds . Not it seems better.

Read about firejail.  https://firejail.wordpress.com/
